# What is the general form of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the general form of the sequence describing an infinite resistor circuit as shown

The sequence can be shown as: 2R,  5R/3,  8R/13,  13R/21,  ...

[image: Infinite system of resistors]

Comment: Are you sure about the third and fourth terms. I get 2R; 5R/3; 13R/8; 34R/21 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence is generated by the ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers:

$$R_n = R\frac{F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n}}$$

$$F_1 = 1, F_2=1,\\F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$$

The Fibonacci numbers have the closed form representation

$$F_n = \frac{\varphi^{n}-(1-\varphi)^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

where $\varphi = (1 + \sqrt{5}) /2 $ 
is the Golden ratio.

Hence,

$$R_n = R\frac{\varphi^{2n+1}-(1-\varphi)^{2n+1}}{\varphi^{2n}-(1-\varphi)^{2n}}$$

Also we would find from circuit analysis, that the nth stage resistance is related to the nth convergent of the continued fraction representation of $\varphi$.

$$\varphi = 1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+...}}$$

Comment: You haven't actually proved that $R_n$ has the stated relation to the Fibonacci numbers, although it is suggested by the first few calculated values.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the physics of it, if $R_n$ is the resistance at step n, then $R_1$ = 2R as stated.

At step $n+1$ you add one resistor in series and one in parallel, so that $R_{n + 1} = R + 1 / (1/ R + 1/R_n)$.

This gives $R_2 = R + 1/(1/R + 1/2R) = R(1 + 2/3) = 5R/3$, and

$R_3 = R + 1/(1/R + 1/(5R/3)) = 13R/8$

$R_4 = R + 1/(1/R + 1/(13R/8)) = 34R/21$

So, that's a recursive formula for the terms of the series. Perhaps someone can resolve it as an expression for $R_n$ as a function of *n*: I regret that I can't. The expression can be simplified somewhat. Let $R_n = R.a_n$ then the terms for $a_n$ are defined by $a_1$ = 2; $a_{n+1} = 1 + [a_n/(1 + a_n)]$

Comment: Just let $b_n = F_{2n+1}/F_{2n}$ (where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number), and note that $(1)\ \ b_1=F_3/F_2=2 $, and $(2)\ \ b_{n+1}=F_{2n+3}/F_{2n+2}=(F_{2n+2}+F_{2n+1})/F_{2n+2}=1+F_{2n+1}/F_{2n+2}=1+1/(F_{2n+2}/F_{2n+1})$ $$= 1+1/((F_{2n+1}+F_{2n})/F_{2n+1})=1+1/(1+F_{2n}/F_{2n+1})=1+1/(1+1/b_n)=1+(b_n/(1+b_n)).$$ That is, the $b_n$ satisfy the same recurrence relation and initial condition you found for the $a_n$, and therefore $a_n = b_n$ for all $n > 0$. (Expression in terms of $n$ alone is then by a standard formula for the Fibonacci numbers, involving the Golden ratio $\phi$.)